# Meteor http calls limitations

Tags: http, meteor

Currently, I use the built-in meteor http method (see http://docs.meteor.com/#http) for issuing http calls, on both my client and my server.

However, I'm experiencing two issues:

- is it possible to cancel a request?
- is it possible to have multiple query parameters which share the same key?

Are these just Meteor limitations, or are there ways to get both to work using Meteor?

I know I could you jquery on the clientside, and there must be a server-side solution which supports both as wel, but I'd prefer sticking with meteor code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "is it possible to cancel a request?"

`HTTP.call()` does not appear to return an object on which we could call something like a `stop()` method. Perhaps a solution would be to prevent execution of your callback based on a `Session` variable?

```js
HTTP.call("GET", url, function(error, result) {
  if (!Session.get("stopHTTP")) {
    // Callback code here
  }
});
```

Then when you reach a point where you want to cancel the request, do this:

```js
Session.set("stopHTTP", true);
```

On the server, instead of `Session` perhaps you could use an [environment variable](https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/49CkbYeyKoa7MyH5R)?

Note that the `HTTP.call()` options object does accept a `timeout` key, so if you're just worried about the request never timing out, you can set this to whatever millisecond integer you want.

> "is it possible to have multiple query parameters which share the same key?"

Yes, this appears to be possible. Here's a simple test I used:

Meteor code:

```js
HTTP.call("GET", "http://localhost:1337", {
  query: "id=foo&id=bar"
}, function(error, result) {
  // ...
});
```

Separate Node.js server: (just the basic example on the Node.js homepage, with a `console.log` line to output the request URL with query string)

```js
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.url);  // Here I log the request URL, with the query string
  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
  });
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

When the Meteor server is run, the Node.js server logged:

```
/?id=foo&id=bar
```

Of course, this is only for GET URL query parameters. If you need to do this for POST params, perhaps you could store the separate values as a serialized array string with `EJSON.stringify`?

Comment: Thanks, this helped me in coming up with a solution. About cancelling the request: I was thinking indeed about using session variables for this. Problem is, I can have multiple requests from the same method, so I'll have to work with assigning IDs to each request (a bit of an ugly workaround).
I can see the GET works. For the posts, I think the only solution is setting the content value of the meteor call (which is essentially the query string). I'll probably generate the content using jqueries parameter parser (which -does- support duplicate keys)